# Correctly applying dropout in CNTK

Tags: neural-network, cntk, dropout

I'm applying dropout as follows in a three hidden layer feed-forward network, using the Python API.  My results are not very good and I wonder if I'm misapplying the dropout layer- is it better to apply it to the input of the dense layer, or internally, to the output of the first linear layer?

```
def dense_layer(input, output_dim, nonlinearity):
    r = linear_layer(input, output_dim)
    r = dropout(r, 0.25)
    r = nonlinearity(r)
    return r;
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about your use case, and the results you are getting? Why do you think that dropout might be the culprit?

Comment: I think the main relevant detail is that I have a very wide, sparse input space (O(1M) inputs, input activations are power-law distributed).  Maybe 25% dropout is too high- I'm re-running at 10%.  I know dropout is the issue because with zero dropout the network performs much better against my validation set.

Answer (score 1):

If 0 dropout works better, why you believe that you need a dropout? Does your network overfit? Do you have other regularization? It would be good to have more detail on the network architecture and the data.

Comment: I'm ok with the possibility that dropout may not yield improved performance- I just want to verify that I'm applying it properly in the code snippet I provided.  The network is very straightforward: O(1M) pre-featurized inputs, three hidden layers, each one defined by the code snippet, and a two node output.

Comment: It is usually applied after the nonlinearity, but it shouldn't make difference here.